# How to save the Battery life in Android Phone?

Tags: android, power-management

I want to know about the battery usage percentage for each apps and available battery power in the android.

Comment: Go to Settings -> About Phone -> Battery -> Battery Use.  There are Application that give you even more detail.  I don't think this is a programming question though?

Comment: [Here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-phone/269#269) you can find a very good answer on that topic!

Comment: **Do you want code for this?**

Comment: @creative MITian:  ya i wanna code

Comment: You can refer the **CommonsWare's** _(Mr. Mark Murphy)_ answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Settings » About phone » Battery use

The following ways are used to save battery life in Android:

```
 •Disable 3G connectivity and tell the device to only use 2G networks.
 •Put your phone on standby mode when you are not using it.
 •Set your screen timeout to the shortest length possible.
 •Use the Power Control widget.
 •Reduce the brightness of your display.
 •Put the device in “Airplane Mode” while on an airline flight.
 •When traveling, take your charger as well as a USB cable with you and get a car charger.
 •Set a reasonable update frequency for apps.
 •Turn off the phone vibration function.
 •Turn off the GPS.
 •Turn off the Bluetooth feature when not needed.
 •Turn off the wireless feature when not needed or set a Wi-Fi timeout.
 •Switch off auto-sync.
 •Do not leave applications running when you don’t need them.
 •Turn off “Background data” usage.
 •Don’t drain the battery.
```

Answer (score 4):

There are no APIs for getting the information you seek, other than gross battery level via `BatteryManager` and a sticky broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

For the most optimised usage and battery backup do the following:-

- Minimum brightness and dont use auto brightness.
- Turn of WIFI, bluetooth, data pack, GPS and auto rotation when not
  needed.
- Set your wallpaper as dark (total black colour wallpaper is the best)
- In Setting->developer option-> turn off Window animation scale, Transition animation scale and Animator duration scale.
- Turn Off Vibrator mode
- Moreover when low battery, change to silent mode instead
  of vibrate mode.